# How to force PDF to open in Yii2 using kartik mpdf extension

Tags: php, yii2, mpdf

I have Kartik mpdf that does not allow me to view the pdf create but forces me to download. How can I force it to open in a browser instead of downloading.

```
 $pdf = new Pdf([
        // set to use core fonts only
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
        // A4 paper format
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        // portrait orientation
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
        // stream to browser inline
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        // your html content input
        'content' => $content,
        // format content from your own css file if needed or use the
        // enhanced bootstrap css built by Krajee for mPDF formatting
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        // any css to be embedded if required
        'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
        // set mPDF properties on the fly
        'options' => ['title' => "Sales report"],
        // call mPDF methods on the fly
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader' => ["Sales Report"],
            'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
        ]
    ]);
     return $pdf->render();
```

Also I tried

```
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
$file = $user.'.pdf';
Yii::$app->response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'inline;filename="'.$file.'"');
```

Comment: try changing `'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER` to `'destination' => I`

Comment: @Mohammad Have tried that to no avail

Comment: I think you should play with the headers, look at the `$pdf->render()` function and try to fix the headers to be something like `Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"`

Comment: Did my answered helped you? if so then select it as the answer

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change destination to `Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,` and be **100% sure** that you're not printing anything nor modifyng headers.

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE,
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_LANDSCAPE,
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_DOWNLOAD,
        'content' => $content,
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
        'options' => ['title' => "Sales report"],
        'methods' => [
            'SetHeader' => ["Sales Report"],
            'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
        ]
    ]);

     return $pdf->render();
```